# Pointer to instantiated object as property of class B (C#)

Tags: c#

*Currently learning C# while coming from C++.*

I have an important class that needs to be shared across multiple classes. Example code in C++:

```
// The important class
class Foo {
    // ...
}

// Class that needs an instance of Foo
class Bar {
public:
    Bar(Foo* foo);
    // ...

protected:
    Foo* m_foo; // <- holds pointer to instantiated Foo-object
}

Bar::Bar(Foo* foo)
    : m_foo(foo) {}
```

And possibly more classes such as `Bar` that need to know the properties of a certain instance of `Foo`. I like using this method for several reasons:

- You don't have to manually update `m_foo` constantly. Especially helpful if there are a number of classes that change its properties and a number of classes that use its properties. It gets out of control real fast.
- No multiple copies of an instantiated `Foo` present.
- You don't have to pass the instantiated `Foo` as an argument all the time.

**Question**: Are there any equivalents available in C#?

---

What is *not* possible or *undesired*:

- Keeping a pointer to a class as property. In other words, copying the C++ code to C#. The keyword `unsafe` does not apply to  pointers to classes. The keyword `fixed` only works inside bodies.
- Passing the object as argument in every single function.
- Updating the newer values to every single class that need it and consequently having a copy lying around everywhere. Not efficient for both memory usage and will be considerably slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would want to do something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    //...
}

public class Bar {
    protected Foo m_foo;

    //C# passes by reference for objects, so any changes to Foo would be reflected
    //in m_foo
    public Bar(Foo foo){
        m_foo = foo;
    }
}

public main(){
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
    Bar bar2 = new Bar(foo);
    foo = null;
    //Both bar and bar2 have the same reference to foo.
    //Any changes to foo from bar will be visible to bar2
    //Even though foo is set to null, the object is not actually removed
    //since both bar and bar2 have a reference to it.
}
```

Comment: Welp, that was dumb. Classes are a reference type so their properties are indeed never copied... Thanks a lot!